# Jquery isn't working in django

Tags: jquery, html, django

When i click on the datefield it shows nothing. I have tested it in chrome as well as firefox. But it is not working

## models.py

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('date_of_birth', 'photo')
    widgets = {'date_of_birth' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})}
```

## html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you check your console for any error ?

Comment: No error, but its  showing this:                                                              18/May/2016 07:14:41] "GET /account/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2792
[18/May/2016 07:14:41] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 @dreamweiver

Comment: @JagdeepSidhu the comment above was about the browser console, not command line output. The browser should give you errors if there's a problem with the Javascript.

Comment: its showing that $().datepicker is not a function @achedeuzot

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the **browser** console ? Are there any errors there ?

It looks like your `class Meta` is at the same indentation than `class ProfileEditForm` which is not good. The `class Meta` needs to be indented inside `class ProfileEditForm` or the changes won't be taken into account. Like so:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:  # <=== Indent this
        model = Profile
        fields = ('date_of_birth', 'photo')
        widgets = {'date_of_birth' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})}
```

Comment: "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function" is showing at console

Comment: @JagdeepSidhu: look at the Tarun Behal's answer. That is maybe the right one for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Assuming your datepicker is not working, You've initialised `$('.datepicker')` before that element got rendered. Move this script tag before the end of body tag and you are good to go. Also datepicker library is not included.

Comment: and how to load this datepicker library

Comment: check the cdn links for this library https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-datetimepicker. Include these in the head section.

Answer (score 0):

Once your page is loaded, try running this in the browser's console
`$('.datepicker').datepicker();`
If this helps in showing the datefield, it means that datepicker is working fine and you just need to add the script for the datepicker at the end of you body tag.

Now, for adding the datepicker.js or any other javascript file you need to add

`class Media:
    js = ('[path to you js file/filename.js]',)`

to the method of "**ProfileEditForm**" in admin.py

**Note:** Also ensure that no jQuery files are linked more than once. They can also create problems.